# Any continuous lift of a smooth map $f:S^1 \to S^1$ to a map on $\mathbb{R}$ is smooth

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, solution-verification, covering-spaces

Suppose $f:S^1 \to S^1$ is a smooth map. I claim that any continuous lift of $f$ to $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth. Let $p: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ be the usual covering map $p(t)=e^{it}$. By inverse function theorem, we note that $p$ is a local diffeomorphism. Now to check smoothness of $g$ at $c$, choose a neighborhood $V$ of $g(c)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ which maps diffeomorphically via $p$ to an open set $p(V)\subset S^1$. Let $W=f^{-1}(p(V))$. Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $c$ in $g^{-1}(V)$ that maps diffeomorphically into an open subset of $W$ via $p$. Then on $U$, $g$ agrees with the composite $p^{-1} f p$. Hence $g$ is locally a smooth function and hence $g$ is smooth.

Is my argument ok? I have used the continuity assumption to get open sets so that the manifold structures remain intact and we stay in a position to apply inverse function theorem.

This argument I am planning to use in the proof of Borsuk Ulam theorem for smooth maps in the case for $S^1$ as instructed in the exercise 2 of section 6 of chapter 2 from the book of Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology.

Confirmation from anyone about the correctness of the proof will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is correct. Trust yourself!

Comment: Thank you very much.